# optimizing tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

Racking my brain for the best way to optimize the following tables so I am not adding redundant info into my database. Looking to see about getting city, county, and zip optimized the best I can.

**city**

- city_id  tinyint 2
- name varchar 16
- population   mediumint   7
- website  varchar 255

**county**

- county_id    tinyint 2
- name varchar 32

**zip**

- zip_id   tinyint 2
- zip  char    5
- some mapping info - still need to figure this out

Then joining with -

**location**

- location_id  tinyint 2
- city_id  tinyint 2
- zip_id   tinyint 2
- county_id    tinyint 2

The location id then sits in the business table, this table is pretty big and I will work on it to see if I can make it more efficient

**business**

- bus_id
- name
- street
- **- location_id  tinyint 2**

Any suggestions? Am I on the right track?

Comment: county names aren't globally unique. you can have "XYZ county, Oregon" and "XYZ county, Nebraska". you have to link counties at the state/province level, not the universe.

Comment: This is just a limited local database so all counties are within one state

Comment: Wow, so that's what it's like when normalization goes crazy. I don't yet fully understand what you mean by "optimize" ... especially I don't get why the street is part of the business table and not the location table. Optimization very much depends on the queries you want to run though, so you probably should mention that. Otherwise your question is really unspecific ;o/

Comment: So I went a little over board? The business table hold info about the business, name, street, phone. What I am running into is there can be a few cities for each zip code and a bunch of zip codes for each city. Same goes for each county.   Each city has same data for it but I don't want to duplicate all the info.

Answer (score 0):

"Normalize, don't over-normalize".

At least move the "county.name" into `City` unless a city can span multiple counties.

I do know that zipcodes and cities can overlap in nasty ways.  Los Altos and Los Altos Hills both have 94022 and 94024.

Comment: I could move the county.name to the zip table.  Each county would be in the table multiple times, anywhere from 1-15 times.  Cities, zips, and counties do over lap in some of the worst ways.